# Is everything that is harmful haram?

Tags: fiqh, usool-ul-fiqh

**Is everything that is harmful for oneself haram?**
Please add references that prove that whatever is harmful for oneself is haram.

Definition of harmful:
Like smoking, eating certain food, or "too much" of certain food.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, the basic Islamic principle is that everything that is proven to be harmful is haram.**

The evidence for the prohibition of that which is harmful is to be found in the Qur’an and the Sunnah.

Allah says in [Surah Al-Baqarah](https://quran.com/2/195):

> “and do not throw yourselves into destruction”

In [Surah An-Nisa](https://quran.com/4/29):

> “And do not kill yourselves (nor kill one another)”

The prohibition on killing oneself is also a prohibition on the means of doing so. Whatever causes harm is haram.

The Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said:

> “There should be neither harming nor reciprocating harm.”

Credits: @Casanova

Comment: Is there consensus on this? Or do some consider it *makruh* instead of *haram* or even *mustahab* to not do it?

Comment: @Uma Actually this answer was taken from user Casanova, I didn't write it. I think he got it from IslamQA. I think this answer here goes through a similar subject in more details: https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39803/15201