# Under which circumstances are we allowed to touch non-mahram?

Tags: halal-haram, non-mahram

Yesterday, I was on my bike, a woman (under the age between thirty and forty or maybe she is early forty) look like upset and asked me if I can give her a ride a little bit further (It was daytime). I refused and go on but I felt bad for that. If it was a guy I would not think twice and gave him a ride.

I know that it is allowed in extreme conditions as mentions in this [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39942/5383) but what if any woman fell down and you want to help that woman. Because I will help a man if he fell down or he needs a lift or some sort but when it's a woman no matter whats the situation I just lower my gaze and walk on.

Am I allowed to help a woman when she is in distress or not?

Answer (score 2):

It is forbidden for non-mahram to ride that close as on bike, don't feel bad. You have done good for both yourself and her. Allah knows better and this apparent favor could have ended in problem for both yourself and her.

However in such situation you can stop and inquire about problem and if possible you can assist by arranging something like taxi for her.

Answer (score 2):

The situation that you raised regarding your bike is not extreme. I myself have faced similar situations multiple times and instead of dropping them by my bike, I prefer hiring them a taxi/rickshaw/uber etc..

But if there is a woman who desperately needs help and there are no other options left which include not touching, in that case I think we can surely help them. Rest Allah (SWT) knows the best what is in our hearts.

Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said "***The reward of deeds depends upon the intention and every person will get the reward according to what he has intended.***" (Sahih Bukhari, Kitab-ul-Imaan, Hadith No. 53)

This hadith itself clears many misconceptions that we mostly have.